# Drawable canvas is rendering lines at wrong position

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a canvas which the user can draw on.
However i've run into some issues that i have trouble understanding why they occur in the first place.

The further away from the canvas origo point (0,0) the further away the line is drawn. Something is wrong, but i can't seem to figure out what.

I've prepared a jsFiddle with an example of the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7LYWZ/13/)

```
$(canvas).on('mousedown', handlePress);
$(canvas).on('mousemove', handleMove);
$(canvas).on('mouseup', handleRelease);

function handlePress(e){
    drawing = true;    
    startx = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    starty = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
}

function handleMove(e){
    if (drawing){
        var newX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
            newY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startx, starty);
        ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
        ctx.stroke();

        startx = newX;
        starty = newY;
    }
}

function handleRelease(e){
    drawing = false;
}
```

I've tried using clientX/clientY instead of pageX and pageY but with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, apparently the canvas was bigger then it was rendered. I had specified the size in CSS but for it to work i needed to specify the width and height attributes of the canvas element in html.

Comment: yeah ... I was about to write this as an answer. It is a common pitfall when working with canvas